# Does the series $\sum\frac{(n!)^2\cdot4^n}{(2n)!}$ diverge or converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the series $\sum \frac{(n!)^2\cdot4^n}{(2n)!}$ converge or diverge?

Comment: are you tried ratio test ?

Comment: yes, and ratio test fail

Comment: $\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{((n+1)!)^2 4^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!}\right)}{\left(\dfrac{(n!)^2 4^n}{(2n)!}\right)} = \dfrac{(n+1)^2 4}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} \to 1$ as $n\to\infty$, so the ratio test fails to answer the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: As noted, even if "${}\to 1$" is called "failure for the ratio test", in fact if we have "${} > 1$ for all $n$", then the series diverges.  And here $4n^2+8n+4 >  4n^2+6n+2$.

Answer (score 8):

$4^n = \sum_{k=0}^{2n} \binom{2n}{k} \ge \binom{2n}{n}$, so the terms of this series are all at least one.  (In particular, they don't converge to zero.)

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{(n!)^24^n}{(2n)!}=\dfrac{2^n\prod_{r=1}^n(2r)}{2^n\prod_{r=1}^n(2r-1)}=\dfrac{\prod_{r=1}^n(2r)}{\prod_{r=1}^n(2r-1)}$

Now $\dfrac{2r}{2r-1}>1$ for $2r-1>0$

Answer (score 2):

Recall Stirling's Formula

$$n!=\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)$$

Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(n!)^2\,4^n}{(2n)!}&=\frac{(2\pi n)\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}4^n}{\sqrt{4\pi n}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}\left(1+O\left(\frac1n\right)\right)\\\\
&=\sqrt{\pi n}+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)\\\\
&\to \infty\,\,\text{as}\,\,n\to \infty
\end{align}$$

Comment: Typo: It should be $\sqrt{\pi n}$

Comment: Thats the mistake I'm pointing out.

Comment: Got it!  Nice catch

Comment: Again. I'm trying to tell you that is not correct.

Comment: @Winther Yes.  Good catch!  +1

Answer (score 1):

A bit useless in light of Steven's answer, but nonetheless useful for future ideas. Recall that the Catalan numbers are equal to $\frac{1}{n+1}\binom {2n}n$ and count the number of sequences of length $2n$ of zeros and ones for which the number of ones is always at least that of zeros at any truncation of the sequence. Since there are $4^n$ binary sequences of length $2n$ it follows that $$\frac{1}{n+1}\leqslant 4^n \binom{2n}n^{-1}$$ so the series diverges by comparison to the harmonic series. In fact $$\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}n \simeq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n\pi }}$$

Comment: In fact, the terms of the seres are asymptotically $(\pi n/2)^{1/2}$.